# How to make jsp table row clickable to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp table as follows.

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="patternList">
    <c:forEach var="pattern" items="${patterns}">
        <li class="list-group-item liitem">
            <strong>${pattern.id}:</strong>
            <span class="pull-right" onclick="test('${pattern.name'})">${pattern.name}</span>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

I want to call following javascript function when click on table row. How can I do that.

```
function test (name) {
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Move `onclick="test()"` to `li`?

Comment: still not working. but when i add alert function in jsp itself it works

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have the `jquery` added to the jsp , bind the `onclick` event to the class `pull-right` ,

```
$(document).on('click', '.pull-right', function(){
  alert("I am clicked and value inside me is " + this.textContent );
});
```

`this.textContent` retrieves the value inside the `span`

Comment: Is there any other way to call javascript function, because I want to pass parameters from jsp to function test()

Comment: Do you need to pass the `span` tag value to the function . Can you post the code you are trying

Comment: with my answer you can do so . Dont you use jquery ? or you need it to be done with js alone

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to do it with js alone

Comment: Can you use `getElementById()` function ? and if you could here is the js version http://jsfiddle.net/San_Krish/zv37ejuw/